# mapping months to axis built with yeardays?

Tags: r, ggplot2, lubridate

I have a number of plots of the sort:

```
ggplot(aes(x=yearday, y=numeric.result)) + ...
```

where "yearday" was obtained using the `yday()` function from `lubridate`.

I would now like the x-axis labels to display months rather than yearday, and I can't seem to find a straightforward way to do this. It surely involves `scale_x_continous`, with breaks being the # days/month, and the labels being  abbr. months, but I cannot seem to get the syntax right.

thanks in advance!!

dput(mydat)

```
structure(list(ydays = c(354, 354, 20, 53, 80, 94, 138, 166, 
207, 236, 285, 332, 353, 353, 45, 64, 100, 136, 136, 176, 211, 
211, 240, 240, 269, 288, 288, 323, 347, 24, 49, 77, 100, 140, 
176, 211, 238, 267, 289, 324, 345, 22, 41, 64, 112, 140, 155, 
203, 218, 252, 280, 322, 343, 26, 42, 76, 119, 146, 168, 209, 
229, 259, 293, 334, 342, 19, 38, 66, 109, 138, 164, 192, 229, 
255, 278, 305, 339, 17, 37, 67, 108, 122, 170, 191, 228, 261, 
296, 318, 347, 17, 50, 78, 106, 134, 156, 204, 232, 247, 288, 
317, 345, 14, 14, 51, 51, 84, 107, 141, 168, 203, 231, 282, 316, 
345, 345, 345, 5, 51, 69, 69, 103, 133, 167, 195, 217, 258, 285, 
348, 19, 40, 75, 97, 145, 159, 194, 221, 251, 280, 312, 340, 
18, 39, 67, 108, 143, 165, 187, 227, 256, 283, 313, 339, 339, 
10, 44, 72, 101, 135, 156, 198, 226, 254, 276, 312, 338, 36, 
91, 133, 154, 218, 42, 64, 132, 162, 188, 252, 281, 307), result = c(0.22, 
1.688, 0.606, 0.794, 1.211, 1.013, 1.272, 1.142, 0.812, 0.557, 
0.421, 0.91, 1.171, 0.522, 1.002, 1.028, 0.917, 0.634, 1.494, 
0.972, 1.194, 0.609, 1.466, 0.359, 0.418, 0.278, 1.291, 0.754, 
0.798, 0.404, 0.495, 0.621, 0.859, 0.625, 0.851, 0.226, 0.147, 
0.264, 0.306, 0.189, 0.247, 0.646, 0.893, 0.519, 1.149, 0.876, 
0.236, 0.943, 0.846, 0.724, 0.417, 0.626, 0.667, 0.461, 0.794, 
0.558, 0.3, 0.61, 0.542, 0.35, 0.569, 0.172, 0.082, 0.118, 0.278, 
0.468, 0.403, 0.455, 0.397, 0.357, 0.357, 0.245, 0.208, 0.312, 
0.12, 0.168, 0.099, 0.383, 0.638, 0.457, 0.637, 0.723, 0.553, 
0.591, 0.246, 0.488, 0.169, 0.505, 0.248, 0.577, 0.436, 0.496, 
0.519, 0.47, 0.439, 0.162, 0.084, 0.06, 0.209, 0.104, 0.116, 
1.31, 0.306, 1.355, 0.122, 0.391, 0.467, 0.7, 0.538, 0.407, 0.39, 
0.124, 0.152, 1.185, 0.154, 1.26, 0.297, 0.778, 1.491, 0.378, 
0.27, 0.629, 0.574, 0.496, 0.432, 0.374, 0.116, 0.28, 0.409, 
0.624, 0.501, 0.973, 0.152, 0.472, 0.674, 0.2, 0.234, 0.2, 0.02, 
0.362, 0.3, 0.44, 1.22, 0.415, 0.782, 0.66, 0.567, 0.418, 0.333, 
0.26, 0.166, 0.414, 0.414, 0.134, 0.509, 0.43, 0.218, 0.437, 
0.304, 0.344, 0.258, 0.17, 0.175, 0.487, 0.506, 0.293, 0.435, 
0.443, 0.352, 0.499, 0.456, 0.577, 0.479, 0.241, 0.552, 0.262, 
0.199, 0.131)), .Names = c("ydays", "result"), row.names = c(NA, 
-178L), class = "data.frame")
```

CODE

```
ggplot(mydat,aes(x = ydays, y = result)) + geom_point() +  geom_line() + theme_bw()
```

So, here you can see the data are correctly plotted on Day1 (Jan1) through Day 365 (Dec31), but I would simply like the month indicated on the x-axis for clarity in reading the plots. Note that there is no year associated with the x-axis.

Hope this helps explain my situation!
best!!

Comment: Would you be able to share your actual code for ggplot as well as sample data? In this way, someone would be able to help you. :)

Comment: I could surely take the time to do that ,I just thought that this was a targeted enough question (months mapped to ydays) that someone could answer as an aside, really. In fact, I'm kinda surprised this has not come up before (I looked pretty hard). I'll make something up and post.

Comment: That would be great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about adding `scale_x_continuous`? There is probably a better way to do this, but the following works:

```
scale_x_continuous(breaks = cumsum(c(1, 31, 30, 28, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30)), 
                   label = c('Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'Mai', 'June', 
                             'July', 'Aug', 'Sept', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'))
```

Comment: Thanks user1707525! Your code worked, but the scale_x_continuous solution of Shadow is sharp, n'est pa?. Shadow, are you German, perhaps? Anyway, it was cumsum() that I was missing in my tries, thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

How about this (with all months having 30 days for example brevity)?

```
data <- data.frame(yday=1:360, values=rnorm(360))

months <- c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "June", "July", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec")

labels <- rep("", times=360)
labels[1 + (0:11 * 30)] <- months

ggplot(data, aes(x=yday, y=values)) +
    scale_x_continuous(breaks=data$yday, labels=labels) + 
    geom_point() +  geom_line() + theme_bw()
```